# naming convention for react hooks and props?

Tags: reactjs

Component's props names and local state variable names are collide. Is there any naming convention followed globally? See "selected" props and state

```
function Select({options,selected,onSelect}){

    let [selected,setSelect]=useState(selected)

    //... useeffect to update local state if props changes

    function setSelectLocal(){
       setSelect(e.target.value)
       onSelect(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
    <select onChange={onSelect} value={selected}>
        {options.map((option)=><option>{option}</option>)}
    </select>  
   )
}
```

Thanks

Comment: check argument "selected" and usestate declaration. Anyway It throws duplicate declaration error. Still If better naming convention may avoid while typing the code

Answer (score 2):

I would say `const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('default value')`.

However, what might be a better option is let the parent component handle the state and simply pass down the handler via props.

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('default value')

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      // other stuff here
      <ChildComponent options={stuff} onChange={onChange} selectedValue={selectedValue} />
    </div>
  )
}

function ChildComponent({ options, onChange, selectedValue }) {
  return (
    <select onChange={onChange} value={selectedValue}>
      {options.map((option)=><option>{option}</option>)}
    </select>  
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My Suggestion is to rename the prop variable to "`org[prop name]`"

```
function Select({options, selected: orgSelected, onSelect}){

    let [selected,setSelect]=useState(orgSelected)

    //... useeffect to update local state if props changes

    function setSelectLocal(){
           setSelect(e.target.value)
           onSelect(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <select onChange={onSelect} value={selected}>
            {options.map((option)=><option>{option}</option>)}
        </select>  
    )
}
```

Answer (score -3):

#### Concise

I'd base the name on the semantics of either the value or the setter, for example:

`const [opened, open] = useState(false);`

Which works well if the natural language offers a good pair for state and action.
That's not always clear, because would should it not be `open, open` (adjective and verb?).

#### Fallback

It's often to see something like this in docs, which is a reasonable default

`const [progress, set_progress] = useState({});`

Because `progress, progress` (noun, verb) would lead to identical names.